# Grant permissions to a macOS app to edit files in a users preferences folder?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm learning Swift at the moment and trying to develop a macOS app to edit a PLIST file in the user's preferences directory (Users/{username}/Library/Preferences).

I've found some outdated information about editing my app's Info.plist file to allow for user selected directories to be edited:

```
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
<true/>
```

But Xcode no longer uses that in project templates.

What are the steps required to allow my newly generated macOS app to edit files in the user's preferences directory?

Comment: You would have to turn off sandboxing, or else the user would have to invite you into the Preferences folder (not easy because most users don't know how to see it).